# add linker to existing sails project

Tags: node.js, linker, sails.js, sails-layout

I am new to sails. I've been developing a sails web application. I started a new app with out linker. Now I want to add linker to project with functionalities. More over I've created "linker" folder in assets. When I include a file to linker it is not importing that file to "layout". But it is importing files from "js/styles" folder.

Add linker to existing sails project.
otherwise, when I add a file it is importing after "impoter.less". Because of that external styles overriding the properties, which shouldn't happen.